# Is this a valid Javascript algorithm to tell if a variable is a prime number?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

In my web programming class we're practicing some basic JavaScript skills by creating a program that takes a user input via prompt, runs it through some code, and tells if it's a prime number or not. The instructions for the algorithm are here:

> 1. Start.
> 2. Display a prompt dialog box and store the user's input in UI.
>
>    - Store UI acquired from a prompt dialog box.
>    - Parse UI as a Base-10 integer and assign it to variable TV.
> 3. Initialize the HITS counter to zero.
> 4. Initialize the DD variable to the value of TV.
> 5. While DD is greater than zero, repeat the following block of two steps:
>
>    - Test if TV is evenly divisible by DD (that is if the remainder of TV/DD equals zero).
>      If so, increment HITS by 1.
>    - Decrement DD by 1.
> 6. Display results within an HTML paragraph the browser's document window as seen in the
>    Sample OUTPUT.
>
>    - The string UI.
>    - The string " is"
>    - If HITS is greater than 2, then display the string " not"
>    - The string " a prime number."
> 7. End.

I tried to follow these instructions and came up with this algorithm.

```
function checkPrime() {
    var HITS = 0; // Quantity of successful integer divisions.
    var UI = prompt("Please enter a whole number to test as a prime number."); // Prompts the user to enter a number to test, stored in User Input;
    var TV = parseInt(UI,10); // Parses the string to int, stores it in Test Variable
    var DD = TV; // Sets Division Denominator to the Test Variable

    while (DD > 0) {
      if (TV % DD == 0) {
        HITS = HITS++;
      } else {
      DD = DD--;
    }

    if (HITS > 2 || TV == 1 ) {
          document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = UI + "is not a prime number.";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = UI + "is a prime number.";
    }
  }
}
```

I'm pretty rusty on my JavaScript since I started my C++ class. Does this algorithm seem to be valid? Also, if possible, how can I trigger this algorithm to run every time the page is refreshed?

Comment: A candidate for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If you just run the code yourself, you'll be able to test its accuracy

Comment: @Meichi Run and test your code in jsfiddle

Comment: Hopefully, this web programming class is teaching you the difference between `var`, `let` and `const` and when to use each of them. I'm going to say it, all uppercase variable names in javasctipt is just weird. Normally it is lowerCamelCase

Comment: Yeah, like @JonP said there are some common variable naming conventions in JavaScript. They're not universal, but generally variables use camelCase. In some cases, for example for the name of a class or an enum (enums aren't part of the JS spec but you can create objects like them, and they exist in TypeScript) where PascalCase is more common. On the algorithm front, you can speed things up by starting at half your test variable. Also, `DD = DD--` will work but it's a little bit of unnecessary double-handling, you can just do `DD--` or `DD -= 1`. Same goes for `HITS = HITS++;`

Comment: Following on from @MarkHanna, the algorithm instructions you have been given arn't great. The loop continues unnecessarily once a successful division has been done. There is no need, once you have that you know you have a number that is not prime and you can break the loop.

Comment: It is also not so great that you are told to use obscure 2-letter names for your variables. Variable names should be descriptive, like `userInput` instead of `UI`, and `testNumber` instead of `TV` (which seems short for Test Variable, which is crazy: of course it is a variable), and `denominator` instead of `DD`. With all the comments here, I think you should conclude you are not on the greatest programming class :/

Comment: Without judgment on the algorithm given, if you really need to follow it to the letter, you are supposed to build the output string, adding the word "not" if it's not a prime number. Plus nothing's said about 1 not being prime. Really depends if you need to follow the instructions to the letter or not.

Comment: "Does this algorithm seem to be valid?"  If implemented exactly as specified it will correctly report whether a positive integer is prime, except for an error at `1`, which is neither prime nor composite.  But it is horribly inefficient. the naming convention is bizarre for JavaScript, and it seems to have been written by someone who has no place teaching beginners.

Answer (score 2):

The code will not work: it will loop forever because `DD` will never be decremented. And this is because of several reasons:

- The decrement of `DD` should happen *always*, not only when `TV` is divisable by `DD`, so your code should not have an `else`.
- You may have thought that `DD` was assigned a new value in each iteration because the indentation of your code is wrong (In fact, the output to HTML happens in each iteration and this is hard to spot because of this misleading indentation).
- Even if the `DD` assignment would have been executed, it is in fact not changing anything, because of the weird combination of `D--` and an assignment. `D--` will evaluate to `D`, and the decrement happens *after* that evaluation, but since the evaluated value is assigned back to `D`, this decrement is undone. The same issue happens with `HITS`. You should just do `D--;` and `HITS++;`
- Maybe you didn't provide the complete solution, but you should *call* your function somewhere. This could be a plain call below the function, or it could be a button on your HTML page that has a click handler that will call it.

Here is a correction to make the code aligned with the instructions:

```js
function checkPrime() {
    var HITS = 0; // Quantity of successful integer divisions.
    var UI = prompt("Please enter a whole number to test as a prime number."); // Prompts the user to enter a number to test, stored in User Input;
    var TV = parseInt(UI,10); // Parses the string to int, stores it in Test Variable
    var DD = TV; // Sets Division Denominator to the Test Variable

    while (DD > 0) {
        if (TV % DD == 0) {
            HITS++;
        }
        DD--;
    }
    document.getElementById('demo').textContent = UI + " is ";
    if (HITS > 2) {
        document.getElementById('demo').textContent += "not ";
    }
    document.getElementById('demo').textContent += "a prime number.";
}

checkPrime();
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

#### Other comments

Not related to your question, but there are several other comments to make on the assignment:

- The described algorithm has a problem, which apparently you detected, as you had added the `TV == 1` test in the `if` condition. The
  *"If HITS is greater than 2"* test does not correctly identify that 1 is not prime. I actually think the *intention* was to have *"If HITS is **different** from 2"*. In that case 1 will be correctly identified as not a prime, since every prime has exactly 2 distinct divisors (itself and 1).
- There is a common practice to name variables in camelCase. All upper case is usually reserved for constants.
- Variable names should be descriptive. 2-letter abbreviations are not a good practice. There are a few exceptions to this rule: One-letter variables are often used for loop variables (like `i`), but this is not your case.
- Assigning to the `innerHTML` property should be reserved for when you actually have HTML encoded content, but for plain text (your case) you should really assign to the `textContent` property.
- Using `prompt` for getting user input isn't that great. I doubt it is good to use it in a training class, only to tell afterwards that students should really not use it, and use `input` and `button` elements instead.
- `parseInt` isn't that great because it will actually return 13 when the input was "13o". Using the unary `+` or `Number` function are better ways to convert input to a number.
- JavaScript (and other languages) have the `for` loop for what you need to happen with `DD`. It can replace your `while` loop.
- There should really be a check that the input can be converted to a number, and if not there should be some message to the user.
- It is not good practice to have a function that deals with both business logic (prime check) and input/output concerns. Those should better be separated.

Here is a version that takes this into account, but which would (necessarily) not follow all the instructions:

```js
function checkPrime(testNumber) {
    let hits = 0;
    for (let denominator = testNumber; denominator > 0; denominator--) {
        if (testNumber % denominator == 0) {
            hits++;
        }
    }
    return hits == 2; // a prime number has EXACTLY 2 divisors
}


const buttonCheck = document.getElementById('check');
const inputElement = document.getElementById('input');
const outputParagraph = document.getElementById('demo');

function handleClick() {
    const userInput = inputElement.value;
    const testNumber = +userInput;
    if (Number.isNaN(testNumber)) {
        outputParagraph.textContent = "This is not a valid number.";
    } else if (checkPrime(testNumber)) {
        outputParagraph.textContent = testNumber + " is prime.";
    } else {
        outputParagraph.textContent = testNumber + " is not prime.";
    }
}

buttonCheck.addEventListener("click", handleClick);
```

```html
Please enter a whole number to test as a prime number: <input id="input"><button id="check">Check</button><br>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

There are better, more efficient methods to do prime checks. An easy improvement is to start with `denominator` being `inputNumber-1` and to quit the loop one step earlier, i.e. when `denominator` is not greater than 1. This way you exclude the two divisors that every number has -- it is unnecessary to test them. If with this improvement your code still finds a divisor that evenly divides `inputNumber` then it is immediately clear that the number is not a prime, so you could exit the loop.

Comment: And of course starting with `2` and working up to `sqrt (n)` instead of from `n` down to `1` will markedly improve the speed as well.

Comment: Yes, the whole topic of efficient prime finding is a long story. You can then add that stepping with 2 (from 3 onwards) is better, that using a wheel method is better, ... a sieve, ...etc.

Comment: And of course there's the difference between prime testing and prime generation, efficient sieves, pseudo-primes, and so on.  Careful or we'll summon Will Ness.  :-).  My biggest concern is the instructor who would assign such a detailed algorithm and do it so inefficiently.  Perhaps improvements will be the next lesson.